# MVC SQLQuery comparing database date with current date

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework-4

I've been trying to get a list of records in a table where the column scheduledate > today(current date + time)

```
var billPays = from s in db.BillPays.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM BillPay WHERE " + 1 + " = Active AND "  + DateTime.Now + " > ScheduleDate").ToList()
            select new BillPayModel
            {
                //model             
            };

             return View(billPays);
```

unfortunately this is not returning anything. Can some one help?

Comment: What du you want with that: " + 1 + " = Active.

Comment: Try add a copied data value, from the database? what is shedule date?

Comment: as you suggested in your own answer, an example schedule date is 2013/10/19 12:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var billPays = from s in db.BillPays.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM BillPay WHERE '"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")+"' > ScheduleDate").ToList()

select new BillPayModel
    {
            //model             
    };
```

Comment: thats works and i tried that, but when i enter the datetime.now() it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
string myQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM BillPay WHERE 1 = Active AND {0:s} > ScheduleDate", DateTime.now);
var billPays = from s in db.BillPays.SqlQuery(myQuery).ToList();
select new BillPayModel
        {
            //model             
        };

         return View(billPays);
```